# `CSS Font Lading API` issues with Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

In my `angular` library I am trying to use the [Font loading Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) for that I have created a `declaration` file like this: ( index.d.ts)

```
// Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-font-loading/

type CSSOMString = string;
type FontFaceLoadStatus = 'unloaded' | 'loading' | 'loaded' | 'error';
type FontFaceSetStatus = 'loading' | 'loaded';

interface FontFace {
  family: CSSOMString;
  style: CSSOMString;
  weight: CSSOMString;
  stretch: CSSOMString;
  unicodeRange: CSSOMString;
  variant: CSSOMString;
  featureSettings: CSSOMString;
  variationSettings: CSSOMString;
  display: CSSOMString;
  readonly status: FontFaceLoadStatus;
  readonly loaded: Promise<FontFace>;
  load(): Promise<FontFace>;
}

interface FontFaceSet {
  readonly status: FontFaceSetStatus;
  readonly ready: Promise<FontFaceSet>;
  check(font: string, text?: string): Boolean;
  load(font: string, text?: string): Promise<FontFace[]>;
}

declare global {
  interface Document {
    fonts: FontFaceSet;
  }
}
```

In my index.ts file I imported and start to use the api:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of ibo-shared-lib
 */
/// <reference path = "./index.d.ts"

if ((document as any).fonts.ready) {
  const myriadfonts = new FontFace('MyriadPro-Regular', 'url(./src/assets/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.ttf)');

  document.fonts.add(myriadfonts);
}

export * from './src/lib/component/index';
export * from './src/lib/directives/index';
export * from './src/lib/pipes/index';
export * from './src/lib/services/index';

export * from './src/lib/ibo-wrapper/ibo-wrapper.module';
export * from './src/lib/ibo-shared-lib.module';
```

But I am still getting an error as follows:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FontFace'.`
`error TS2339: Property 'fonts' does not exist on type 'Document'.`

so what is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today (v4.3), TypeScript doesn't have the type definitions for CSS font loading. (Edit: this should change in the next version, v4.4)

Fortunately, these definitions are available on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/css-font-loading-module). You can install them on your project with npm for example:

```sh
npm install --save @types/css-font-loading-module
```

Once these types are installed, you can remove your `index.d.ts` file, and import the types like this:

```js
import 'css-font-loading-module'

document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
  const myriadfonts = new FontFace('MyriadPro-Regular', 'url(./src/assets/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.ttf)')

  document.fonts.add(myriadfonts)
})
```

([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgMYGcUFoBmEB2N0A2EAhgCbA4Dm6IEpArgQKYICwAUB6REvSE3gB02PCkFQmZAJ6CYACwEAKTPRxIYwXIoCUcAN4c4cJLhTwQUqMDIiYKOAF44OJgHc4AMVwwPxJE0UEAFlLa1IABSgIdAAlJkpGYigEABpEeigCRUEAehQoJBziNCY7HNsUHJCrMkjouISCJNkYTG0EbQBuDkM4bl5+IQrBMlJFCxrSCq6OAF8Z9iA))

By the way, since `document.fonts.ready` is a promise, you *can't* simply use this:

```js
if (document.fonts.ready) {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, since a promise is *truthy*, you'll always end up running the code inside the `if` statement, which is not your intent I'm assuming.